# Запись символов вместо чисел в файл Java

Tags: java

Программа смотрит в файл input.txt считывает три числа и высчитывает по формуле четвертое число. Потом должна записать это число в файл output.txt но вместо этого пишет совершенно другое. Когда переменная s имела значение 44 она записывала запятую, при этом на консоли выводилось положенное 44, когда имела значение 100 записывала букву d. В чем может быть проблема и как её исправить?

```
package com.company;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"), "UTF-8");
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int m = scanner.nextInt();
        int k = scanner.nextInt();
        int s = (m/(k+2)*2);
        System.out.print(s);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("output.txt");
        writer.write(s);
        writer.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Метод write(int a) у OutputStreamWriter и у его наследника FileWriter записывает в файл символ с кодом a. Достаточно преобразовать int к String и все будет ок. Например так: writer.write(s + "");

Comment: Как вы сказали, добавил writer.write(s + ""); в итоге получаю "44,".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте со стримами

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Files.write(Paths.get("output.txt"), 
                Files.lines(Paths.get("input.txt")).map((words) -> {
                    final String[] ints = words.split(" ");
                    return String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(ints[1]) / (Integer.valueOf(ints[2]) + 2) * 2);
                }).collect(Collectors.joining("\r\n")).getBytes());
    }
}
```